# Save images in R

Tags: r, cowplot

Does anyone use the function `save_plot` from the package `cowplot` to save the picture instead of `ggsave`. How we can set up the output? I did use the default setting and the output pic was set
into `AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpuSVbq4\\tree_test2730600e55ae.pdf"`

But when I go to that folder, the picture did not appear.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
pdf("/tmp/example.pdf")
plot(1:10,sin(1:10)) # Draw here your plot
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
p1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = cty, y = hwy, color = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  theme_half_open()
file1 <- tempfile("file1", fileext = ".png", tmpdir = getwd())
save_plot(file1, p1)
```